# Visualizing world map using D3.js but cant visualize the json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, world-map

I am trying to make a world map with D3.js, I have a problem visualizing the countries.json file.

This is the code:

```
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", move);


var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var height = width / 2;

var topo,projection,path,svg,g;

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var tooltip = d3.select("#container").append("div")
              .attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

setup(width,height);


function setup(width,height){
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
              .translate([(width/2), (height/2)])
              .scale( width / 2 / Math.PI);

path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom)
    .on("click", click)
    .append("g");

g = svg.append("g");

};
d3.json("countries.json", function(error, json) {  
  var countries = topojson.object(json, json.objects.countries).features;
  topo = countries;
  draw(topo);

});

function draw(topo) {

  svg.append("path")
     .datum(graticule)
     .attr("class", "graticule")
     .attr("d", path);
```

and this is the json file that Im using:

```
{"type":"Topology","objects":{"countries":{"bbox":[-179.99999999999986,-55.52450937299982,180.00000000000014,83.61347077000005],"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"id":"AFG","arcs":[[0,1,2,3, ...
```

this is the error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined
```

Has anyone an idea what is going wrong and how i kan solve it?

Comment: Without any further information, I'd say that `draw` is not defined.

Comment: sorry, draw is a function, i will edite it

Comment: The argument to your function is `topo` and you're referencing `graticule`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem loading the JSON file. In this line...

```
var countries = topojson.object(json, json.objects.countries).features;
```

If `json` is undefined it will use 'undefined' as the first argument, but the second argument will throw exactly the error you mentioned, because `undefined` does not have a property called `objects`

Comment: thanks, it makes sense, but i cant find a way to solve it right now.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to be a browser security problem and I solved it is follow:

In the computer “command prompt” go to the file directory and enter:

```
Python –m SimpleHTTPServer
```

It cost me allot of headache, but that did the job.
Thank you for helping